# Users with ACL not found in query

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am using Parse, and I have around 500 users. I just recently ran into a new issue where only some Users have their ACL's set, and they are not found when querying.Basically, I cannot access any users who have an ACL set. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: For each ACL, check if publicAccess:read is set or not. If not, that row will be skipped (except for the users that are "eventually" autorized to see it). If you want also to modify it, the publicAccess need to be both read and write

Comment: Both read and write access are set to true. For example, {"object_id_goes_here":{"read":true,"write":true}}.

Comment: I've posted an answer. Hope it will works for your case

Comment: Thanks for the response but that did not solve my problem. I am not using any cloud code.

Comment: Can you edit the ACLs on a new version of the app? You could edit the ACLs on next login and then query normally.

Comment: I tried to edit the ACL's manually inside Parse, but that did not work. I gave each user public read/write access and they are still not found in query.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make a custom function or background job in the cloud code (javascript) of your Parse application, and try to do something like this:

```
// bypass ACL restriction
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

// take an user for test, fetch it
var someFetchedUser = ......;

// creating new acl object
var newACL = new Parse.ACL();

// define public read access on this acl object ( means: all users can read the owner row
// that will keep this acl ( so the someFetchedUser )
newACL.setPublicReadAccess(true);
// define possibility to write / delete just to this user ( so, the owner user himself )
newACL.setWriteAccess(someFetchedUser.id,true);

// set the new ACL to the fetched user ( overwrite previous one )
someFetchedUser.setAcl(newACL);

// apply modification ( should works since you're working with masterkey from the scratch )
someFetchedUser.save().then(function(savedUser){
   // Do your stuff..
},function(err){
   // Damn!!!! something was wrong....
});
```

It should change the ACL of an user ( change as needed to apply it to all the users)

Hope it helps!